# Fixed header ends up in the middle of the page when scrolling (samsung galaxy s3)

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I am working on a html/css mobile project. I am NOT using jQuery Mobile.

I have a fixed header at the top of the page. However on the Samsung Galaxy S3, when I have a page with lots of content that scrolls off the screen, when i scroll the header ends up moving into the middle of the screen.

So as i scroll the header moves and then stays in the middle of the screen and doesnt move back up! Its fine in iPhone etc. My code:

```
.headerTop {
   z-index: 9;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #fff;
   height: 60px;}
```

Is there any way around this? Can this be fixed with css or does it need jQuery or something fancy to get around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding

```
top:0
```

to your css class .headerTop

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css `.headerTop{top:0;}`

Comment: hey that's what I said 5 minutes ago!

Comment: yes your answer is right, but i saw your answer after posting mine any way i vote u up

Answer (score 0):

.headerTop{
top:0
}
will definitely solve your problem